# How to call C# method from javascript and use javascript variable as parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to call C# method from javascript and use javascript variable as parameters.
Example:

`<script type="text/Javascript">var value = "@Tool.GetValue(GroupCode)";</script>`

where GroupCode is a javascript variable.

I tried
`<script type="text/Javascript">var value = "@Tool.GetValue(@:GroupCode)";</script>`
`<script type="text/Javascript">var value = @{@Tool.GetValue(GroupCode)";}</script>`
and find reference from google but cannot find solutions.

Anyone know my problem solution ?

Comment: This is not possible in MVC. It IS possible in Blazor, search 'Blazor JS Interop'

Comment: It's possible to use the result of a C# method as an argument for a JavaScript function, because the C# is executed server-side and the result can be written into the JavaScript sent to the client. You can't use the result from JavaScript executed on the client in C# executed on the server though, because the JavaScript is executed after the C#. You need either JavaScript executed on the server or C# executed on the client. They are both possible, but not unless you build your app to work that way in the first place. As suggested, Blazor is the way to do the latter.